# Index out of bounds error on running U-SQL locally in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2019, u-sql

I am trying to run a U-SQL script locally in Visual Studio 2019 using the Data Lake tools. I get an error immediately after starting the job by clicking on the "Submit" button on the U-SQL file.

2021-08-12 06:32:45 [Info] ========== Starting job locally ==========

2021-08-12 06:32:47 [Info] *** (-1, -1) Internal error! Index was outside the bounds of the array.

I can't tell why this error happens and at what step. I am using a user defined Applier in the U-SQL script but the Applier has been running correctly in the actual Azure data pipeline and on my manager's machine, so its not an issue with the Applier code. But seems to be related to my local machine setup. Where do I find logs for more information?

Comment: You will need to add your script to the question to get any help here, that error can come from a large number of potential places.

Comment: There isn't any issue with the script (works on team mates' machines). Seems to be an issue with local environment setup. Do you know where to find more detailed logs?

Answer (score 0):

This was because Newtonsoft.Json version higher than 12.0.2 is not supported. Got rid of the error by using a lower version of this library.

https://learn.microsoft.com/EN-US/azure/data-lake-analytics/runtime-troubleshoot